# Override Antd global font

Tags: javascript, css, antd

I wouldl like to override the `Antd 5.1.2` global font but can't find any documentation on how to do so.

I've added `Mulish` to my app using the `@fontsource/mulish` dependency. I then import it like so:

```
import "@fontsource/mulish";
```

I've then tried enabling the font

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Mulish" !important;
}

:root{
     font-family: "Mulish", serif !important;
}

body{
    font-family: "Mulish", serif !important;
}
```

but these get overridden by antd.

[image: antd styling]

What is the correct method of overridding the global antd font?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [customize-theme](https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme). There is a `SeedToken` named `fontFamily`, set it to `Mulish` in the `theme.token` property of the `ConfigProvider` component.

```
import { ConfigProvider, Typography } from "antd";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <ConfigProvider
      theme={{
        token: {
          fontFamily: "Mulish"
        }
      }}
    >
      <Typography.Text>Hello World!</Typography.Text>
    </ConfigProvider>
  );
}
```

Output:

[image]

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-currying-rrdphh?file=/src/App.tsx:0-286)